# How did this question get 5 upvotes and become an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

[This is a terrible close vote audit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2885972)

I think it might have been chosen automatically because of the 5 up votes, but even if it wasn't an audit and I came across this on SO I'd vote to close.

I would have picked this flag

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

or

> Questions on professional server, networking, or related
>   infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>   they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be
>   able to get help on Server Fault.

It may have been an advanced question but how is it a programming question?

*Don't get fooled by the code provided in the answer.* The OP wasn't asking for the code.

Anyone agrees? Or I am just totally wrong on this one?

Comment: Personally, I don't know enough about it to say one way or the other, but the contents of the answer certainly suggests it is at least on-topic.

Comment: I think you off on this one.  The wiki for [tag:powershell] says it is a windows command prompt scripting environment.  And historically scripting questions (like this, or bash) are on-topic.

Comment: I would have failed it as well, but I think @psubsee2003 is correct.

Comment: @psubsee2003 shouldn't be taking me 15 minutes to research how to review one close vote. Bad audit is my point - I do accept that the question is ON topic.

Comment: @mehow I don't understand one thing... if you agree the question is on topic why did you vote to close it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I do now accept the fact that this question is on topic for SO (see psubsee 2nd comment). I have not voted to close it. I would have had before I realized the question was on topic for SO. My point here is that its a bad review audit.

Comment: If you thought it was _not_ on-topic when it actually was, it is an _excellent_ review audit.

Comment: @mehow on the contrary. You did try to close it, that's why you failed the audit. The question is on topic, so bottom line your review decision was wrong and the audits exist exactly for this purpose: make the reviewers stop and think before pulling the trigger.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd i am proved wrong in this case. Now we can reverse from *terrible* to *excellent* and use the *terrible* as description of the reviewer ->

Comment: @mehow not sure I follow the thin line of sarcasm, but do hope you learned a lesson... :-)

Comment: Where @psubsee2003 logic fails is that the title and body are different questions. It just so happens to worm Powershell in there, after the initial off-topic spiel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag wiki for [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) says it is a windows command prompt scripting environment. And historically scripting questions (like bash) are on-topic for Stack Overflow, so it would appear to be a perfectly acceptable question.

So I think you are wrong on this one.

> @psubsee2003 shouldn't be taking me 15 minutes to research how to review one close vote. Bad audit is my point - I do accept that the question is ON topic.

I realize no one wants to do 15 minutes of research on a post just to decide to close it or not (I know I don't either).  But for making close decisions, the askers do deserve honest feedback about their posts and not closing good, on topic questions.

The lesson from this is about using the skip button.  I would agree that you don't need to be an expert in the field in order to close a question, however, it also means that you might make a mistake every now and then.  I probably would have failed this audit as well, as it does not read like an on topic question, but it is.  And I'm actually going to learn from this one myself and be more mindful of questions that are completely out of my comfort zone.

Comment: +1 skip if unsure, you don't always need to decide (and if decision is taking more than a few minutes... I usually skip).

Comment: It's not a question about powershell. It's a question about why certain windows services come from MS configured in a particular way.

Comment: Might you also mention the ability to filter questions in the queue by tag and thus only see ones that you are familiar with?