# Failed review audit - for me quite clearly off-topic, can it be removed from the audit set?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed this review audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4243797

For me, it's quite clearly an off-topic question. It asks for a toolkit recommendation and nothing else. Probably it was selected as a good audit as it has 5 upvotes - but that doesn't make it a good question.

Can this be removed from the audit set? I'm all for the audits but we should make sure they are of good quality.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that is downvote and vote-to-close it <- and at +5 -4 I think we have successfully removed it from the audit set.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209268/a-recommendation-question-and-answer-in-an-audit-gotta-be-kidding

Comment: and also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196288/how-did-this-question-get-5-upvotes-and-become-an-audit

Comment: and one more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210819/bad-audit-once-again

Comment: I'll just put this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Audits are automatically selected from posts that appear to "look good". In this case due to heavy up voting. The system cannot know it is actually a completely off topic question that has for some reason been upvoted.

The way to remove a question as a potential audit candidate is to stop it looking so good; just do whatever you tried to do within the audit; downvote it or vote to close.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that. This way we've dealt with this question quite quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

The action you took against this audit shouldn't have been a failure but the system picked a good question for an audit because in the end the question should have been closed and deleted from site.

The problem is that the system can't work out what the correct action should be... It's based on the amount of votes ( like you have already noticed ). I wish there was someone on the other side of cable to approve/reject your action instead of a system...

Don't worry about failing it, it happens to most of us occasionally... if it didn't get you banned then there is nothing to worry about, if it did - then I am sure a mod can lift the ban from your account.